# Error de expresion is not defined he probado de todo y en el video que estoy viendo sale tal cual muestro

Tags: python, error404, calculo, parser, expression

Me da error en el apartado de calculate porque dice que expression no esta definido, que ddebo hacer?

[image]

Me da error en el apartado siguiente:

```
def calculate():
    display_state = display.get()
    try:       
        math_expression = parser.expr(display.state).compile()
        result = eval(math_expression)
        clear_display()
        display.insert(0, result)
    except expression as identifier:
        clear_display()
        display_state(0, "Error")
```

Comment: Tanto el mensaje de error como el código que agregues a la pregunta tiene que estar en forma de texto. Ponte en nuestros zapatos y piensa como sería que tubieras que transcribir el código a partir de una imagen para poder hacer pruebas.

Comment: Tras `except` debes poner `Exception`, y no `expression`

Comment: Me funciona pero me pone que el string object is not callable. Hay alguna forma en la que lo pueda solucionar?

Answer (score 0):

Parece que estás intentando correr el archivo incorrecto. Estás seguro que estas en la carpeta correcta y que el comando para ejecutar está apuntando al mismo archivo? Probablemente hiciste una copia con el mismo nombre y te estas confundiendo. Y otro posible error: "Guardaste" tus cambios antes de volver a correr el archivo?

Comment: Lo que estoy intentando solucionar es que la calculadora me de ponga error si una expression no está definida pero debe de ser que el modulo no está actualizado en el video o que este ya no funciona.